# Zend Framework 2 && ServiceLocator init libraires

Tags: php, zend-framework2, service-locator

I have problem or misunderstanding of zf2's serviceLocator. Which is the right way to get a library/class with serviceLocator, which need configuration in the __construct method.

For example:

```
class PhpVersion extends AbstractTest implements TestInterface
{
    public function __construct($expectedVersion, $operator = '>=')
    {
    }
 }
```

The problem is that, the ServiceLocator's get method requires only one variable - Libraries name, without any place for configuration or dependency

P.S. My solution is with making a factory, but I think there should be a smarter way.

Comment: dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14054797/zf2-get-service-from-service-manager-with-additional-parameter

Answer (score -1):

you can create your own service locator by extending the zends service locator class and customizing the get method to accepts arguments and pass them on to the constructor of that object.